# Ctrl+Click to Simple Click on explorer - AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make Ctrl+Click just simple Click on explorer with AutoHotkey.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe explorer.exe
^LButton:: LButton
```

;

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe explorer.exe    
^LButton:: Send {Ctrl Up}{LButton}
```

I tried these two scripts, but they didn't work.

Still, with ^LButton, I could select multiple files.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^LButton::LButton` shouldn't work, because internally the easy remapping syntax [expands to a send command with `{Blind}`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#actually). Or more clearly said, modifiers, that are held down, are left as is.

However, `^LButton::Send, {Ctrl Up}{LButton}` should be fine.
And it does work on my system as expected.
`{Ctrl Up}` is redundant though, since the `Send` command automatically releases modifiers before sending <sub><sup>(unless in blind mode)</sup></sub>.
Maybe try this just in case:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe explorer.exe    
^LButton::SendInput, {LButton}
#IfWinActive
```

Also switched over to `SendInput`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail)</sup> due to it being the recommended faster and more reliable send mode.